# Where can we change the Description for installation procedure of MAC pkg

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

I am building mac package using `pkgbuild command` of my app(Developed in Xcode). when i install package, i see few steps to be followed.

Is this default one provided by mac pkg installer or can we customise it. Any help is appreciable.thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use productbuild with customised Distribution.dist file.